# Alternative options for svg filters in ie 9

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Recently i started doing some work with svg and stumbled across the idea of svg filters. 
However, soon i realized that this functionality is not supported by ie 9.

Is anyone aware of any fallback technique that i can apply so that i have similar visual effects to those supported by svg filters?

Basically i want to apply filters such as drop shadow, blur etc. to a path element. I thought i could do this using css3 but it seems that css 3 is not fully applicable on svg element

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-shadow-offset-tutorial/

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.rect(188, 40, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.shadowColor = '#999';
    context.shadowBlur = 20;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 15;
    context.shadowOffsetY = 15;
    context.fill();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know that ie9 supports canvas, however we're using svg and not canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at raphaeljs.  http://raphaeljs.com  .  You can extend it, or use current extensions to get filtering in IE